# Replace multiple charcter using regex substitution

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to perform a regex substitution on the output of acpi command. My perl one liner for this is:

```
acpi | perl -F/,/ -alne 'print $F[1] if ($F[1]=~s!\s|%!!)'
```

The output of the above one liner is `87%` whereas my required output is just `87` so it is not replacing `%` in the string.

Now the output of `acpi` command is

```
Battery 0: Discharging, 87%, 05:54:56 remaining
```

and the output of `print $F[1]` is

```
ronnie@ronnie:~$  acpi | perl -F/,/ -alne 'print $F[1]'
 87%   #space followed by 87%#
ronnie@ronnie:~$
```

Now the strange this is if I try the same perl one-liner on:

```
echo " 86%" | perl -nle 'print if s!\s|%!!g'
```

It works fine and outputs `86`.

So, why it is not working with acpi command.

PS: I am aware this can be achieved by using sed/awk but I am interested why my solution is not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your one-liner does not work as you expect because

```
s!\s|%!!
```

replaces *either* a whitespace *or* a percent sign, not both.

If you want it to replace both, add the global `/g` modifier:

```
s!\s|%!!g
```

Just as you coincidentally did in your other example.

You might also consider using a character class instead of alternator:

```
s![\s%]!!g
```

If your output follows the format you showed, you might be better off using a simple regex:

```
echo Battery 0: Discharging, 87%, 05:54:56 remaining|perl -nlwe 'print /(\d+)%/'
87
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

This one works as expected:

```
echo " 86%" | perl -F/,/ -alne 'print $F[1] if ($F[1]=~s!\s*(\d+)%!$1!)'
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `g` modifier

```
acpi | perl -F/,/ -alne 'print $F[1] if ($F[1]=~s!\s|%!!g)'
                                                    ____^
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `s!...!...!` matches the space first and then does nothing else. Try adding the `g` modifier as in `... s!\s|%!!g`.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this and it works perfectly.

```
echo "Battery 0: Discharging, 87%, 05:54:56 remaining" | perl -F, -alne '$F[1]=~s/\s|%//g;print $F[1]'
87
```

Problem is with the `g` modifier.

`g` actually says to replace all the occurrences in the line, but default behaviour is to replace only the first occurrence.
So since there is space at the beginning of `$F[1]`, only space is replaced and rest of the characters in the line are ignored.